# Is there any way to set number of threads , number of blocks and grids for CuPy computation? How?

Tags: python, cupy

I am using Cupy with following code,

```py
import cupy as cp

vals, vecs = cp.linalg.eigh(Array)
```

For above code , I want to set number of threads in the code. How to do it. Let us say for 100 threads execute the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For high-level, NumPy-like APIs, there is currently no public interface to change the grid/block configuration. In addition, many linalg APIs (such as `eigh` in your example) delegate the job to the CUDA Math Libraries solvers, which do not allow users to set grid/block configuration either. I wonder what prompts to this need. It'd be nice if you could elaborate.

Comment: To check the scalability.. By keeping same problem size and varying number of threads, we would like to test.

Comment: Unless you write your own custom kernels, I don't think doing (either weak or strong) scaling analysis like this is viable. Most of CUDA libraries have find-tuned, per-architecture launch configurations.

Comment: Yes Sir... I want to know how to write custom kernel for the same which will use cp.linalg.eigh

Comment: That is not possible either. Internally, `cp.linalg.eigh` calls the eigensolver API from cuSOLVER, but it's a host API. There's no way to write a kernel that calls host functions.